# How to trigger a job only when files in root changed?

Tags: gitlab-ci, monorepo

I have a large NodeJS monorepo and I want to trigger a job when the `package.json` in the root of the monorepo was changed, but not if a `package.json` in any of the contained child projects changed.

```yaml
test:
  script:
    - echo GitLab CI is such a pain sometimes
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"'
      changes:
        - ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/package.json
        - ./package.json
        - /package.json
      when: on_success
    - when: never
```

None of these 3 patterns will trigger the job. Only when I use `package.json` will it trigger, but then it also triggers for *any* changed `package.json`.

I didn't find any mention of what the expected path syntax actually is in the GitLab documentation and trial-and-error is getting me nowhere.

The best approach I could come up with right now is:

```yaml
test:
  script:
    - echo GitLab CI is such a pain sometimes
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"'
      changes:
        - package.json
      when: on_success
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"'
      changes:
        - packages/**/package.json
      when: never
    - when: never
```

But this also doesn't seem to work reliably. As [the documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules) says:

> Rules are evaluated when the pipeline is created, and evaluated in order until the first match. When a match is found, the job is either included or excluded from the pipeline, depending on the configuration.

So once the first rule matches, because *any* `package.json` was changed, the job is included.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a very helpful answer in the [GitLab forums](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/how-to-distinguish-changes-in-root-files-from-changes-in-subfolders/62881), I realized that I must have been making a mistake in my repo.

Just providing `package.json` shouldn't trigger on changes in subfolders. Some other mistake must have caused the pipelines to be triggered.